# API working with POSTMAN but not with fetch

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, content-security-policy

I know there have been lots of questions on this topic and I read them all but not able to resolve my issue so asking here.

I am getting the following error while trying to access an api using fetch-

> Refused to connect to 'https://xxxxx/api' because it violates the
> following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src 'self'
> updates.developer.mozilla.org
> [www.google-analytics.com](http://www.google-analytics.com) stats.g.doubleclick.net"

I don't have any control over this api so I can't add anything to connect-src. When making a fetch(api_url) request I am getting the above error but while making the same GET request from POSTMAN(or directly from url bar of browser) then I am able to receive the response body(which is an xml).

Also while making a fetch request with mode set to 'no-cors' I am able to get a response but not the response body. I want the response body.

**What is POSTMAN doing differently? How can I achieve the same using fetch()?**

Comment: The most obvious answer is that Postman isn't using CORS, but your browser is. Make the request server-side and pass to your front-end.

Comment: @gunwin I tried no-cors mode in fetch but with no-cors you can't get the response body

Comment: This is not about CORS though. The error is about CSP. It is not the server that rejects the request it is your browser refuses to connect because the page you are doing the request **from** has CSP Header that prevents scripts to request third party resources.

Comment: @Yuri got your point but how do I resolve it?

Comment: Change the CSP header on the page where you want this request to work. BTW you don't need to have control over the API response, this should be done on the page where you have your script running (this one should be in your control since you are injecting your script somehow).

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the 'CORS Unblock' chrome extension and then run your application. Also, this error generally occurs when we use an API link as http://'apilink' when the link is https://'apilink' or vice-versa. Please check that as well.